# Installing Gearman PHP extension on Debian 6

Tags: php, linux, debian, gearman

I'm desperately trying to get the Gearman PHP extension working on a Debian 6.

I have all the binaries and sources

```
root@debian:/tmp/pear/install# aptitude search gearman
i   gearman                                                             - A distributed job queue
i A gearman-job-server                                                  - Job server for the Gearman 
i   gearman-tools                                                       - Tools for the Gearman 
i   libgearman-dev                                                      - Development files for the 
i   libgearman4                                                         - Library providing Gearman
```

...but when there are some bugs in the PHP extension confing which don't let me install it

```
# /usr/local/pear/bin/pecl install gearman
downloading gearman-1.1.0.tgz ...
Starting to download gearman-1.1.0.tgz (30,488 bytes)
.........done: 30,488 bytes
3 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
building in /tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootrDO8Ob/gearman-1.1.0
running: /tmp/pear/install/gearman/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20090626
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking whether to enable gearman support... yes, shared
not found
configure: error: Please install libgearman
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/install/gearman/configure' failed
```

The config.m4 has few interesting lines

```
 for i in $PHP_GEARMAN /usr/local /usr /opt/local; do
    if test -r $i/include/libgearman-1.0/gearman.h; then
      GEARMAN_LIB_DIR=/usr/lib
      GEARMAN_INC_DIR=/usr/include/
      AC_MSG_RESULT([found in $i])
      break
    fi
  done
```

First of all there is a reference to "libgearman-1.0" (the same dir name is used in the source code). Installed includes went to /usr/include/libgearman instead. Not a big problem I created a link

```
ln -s libgearman/ libgearman-1.0
```

Also just in case eddied GEARMAN_LIB_DIR and GEARMAN_INC_DIR to point it to the right directories. Unfortunately this is as far I get:

```
./configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20090626
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking whether to enable gearman support... yes, shared
found in /usr
checking for gearman_client_set_context in -lgearman... yes
checking for gearman_worker_set_server_option in -lgearman... no
configure: error: libgearman version 0.21 or later required
```

Do you know what is the easiest way to install this PHP extension on Debian / Ubuntu? I found some propositions on google but non of them worked for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that this doesn't work is that as the error message says, the most recent version of the PHP extension requires libgearman-1.0 (which is why the directory is named 1.0). You'll need to be at least on wheezy (which is the version after debian 6 / squeeze) to get libgearman-1.0.

It might also be a solution to compile libgearman from source, and then use `checkinstall` to create a debian package that you install afterwards, or use the gearman developer ppa available at `https://launchpad.net/~gearman-developers/+archive/ppa`. We've built libgearman, gearmand and the PHP extension on a wide variety of distributions (including Debian, Ubuntu, RHEL4 and SL6) and used checkinstall to get a proper package available.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install make gcc g++
sudo apt-get install libboost-thread-dev libboost-program-options-dev libevent-dev uuid-dev libpq-dev libcloog-ppl0 libcurl4-gnutls-dev
sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev libmariadbclient-dev libsqlite3-dev # option

wget https://launchpad.net/gearmand/1.2/1.1.12/+download/gearmand-1.1.12.tar.gz
tar xvfz gearmand-1.1.12.tar.gz
cd gearmand-1.1.12
./configure
make
sudo make install

sudo useradd -M gearman -s /sbin/nologin -r
sudo mkdir /var/run/gearman /var/log/gearman-job-server
sudo touch /var/log/gearman-job-server/gearman.log
sudo chown gearman:gearman /var/run/gearman /var/log/gearman-job-server

sudo vi /etc/init.d/gearman-job-server
```

**Resources**

- http://yupmin.net/install-gearmand-with-php-supervisor

Answer (score 0):

You can find thorough installation instructions for installing an older version of gearman (0.8.3) here, which may solve your problem
http://blog.andyburton.co.uk/index.php/2012-12/gearman-0-41-with-mysql-persistent-storage-and-php-pecl-0-8-3-with-gearmanmanager-on-ubuntu-12-04/