# How to install Gearman with PHP Extension

Tags: php, compilation, installation, gearman

I'm trying to install Gearman with PHP Extension to use it with PHP-CLI.

I have a Debian 6.0.5 with `php5-cli` and `php-pear` installed.

Thats what I tried

```
# apt-get install php5-dev
# apt-get install gearman-job-server libgearman-dev
# pecl install gearman
```

Thats what I see on the console for `pecl install`

```
downloading gearman-1.1.1.tgz ...
Starting to download gearman-1.1.1.tgz (30,896 bytes)
.........done: 30,896 bytes
3 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootAccnyQ/gearman-1.1.1
running: /tmp/pear/temp/gearman/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20090626
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking whether to enable gearman support... yes, shared
not found
configure: error: Please install libgearman
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/gearman/configure' failed
```

Why is it failing? libgearman is installed ...

Answer (score 14):

> to install Gearman with PHP Extension in Windows OS see
>   [How can i install gearman php extension on Windows OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373363/how-can-i-install-gearman-php-extension-on-windows-os/30593439#30593439)

## install Boost headers

**debian**

```
apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

**fedora**

```
yum install boost-devel
```

## install gperf

**debian**

```
apt-get install gperf
```

**fedora**

```
yum install gperf
```

## install libevent

**debian**

```
apt-get install libevent-dev
```

**fedora**

```
yum install libevent-devel
```

## install uuid

**debian**

```
apt-get install uuid-dev
```

**fedora**

```
yum install uuid-devel
```

## install libcloog-ppl0

**debian**

```
apt-get install libcloog-ppl-dev
```

## install gearmand and libgearman

```
wget https://launchpad.net/gearmand/1.2/1.1.12/+download/gearmand-1.1.12.tar.gz
tar -zxvf gearmand-1.1.12.tar.gz
cd gearmand-1.1.12
./configure
make
make install
```

## install pecl-gearman

```
pecl install gearman
```

## Resources

- http://hasin.me/2013/10/30/installing-gearmand-libgearman-and-pecl-gearman-from-source/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/445904/how-to-install-libboost-devel-on-centos-6-3
- https://serverfault.com/questions/528585/centos-yum-install-libevent-devel-conflict-with-compat-libevent
- http://yupmin.net/install-gearmand-with-php-supervisor
- https://gist.github.com/rafasashi/6f920d07909564bf8e4f

Comment: if

wget https://launchpad.net/gearmand/1.2/1.1.11/+download/gearmand-1.1.12.tar.gz 

fails try to use this one :  

 
wget https://launchpad.net/gearmand/1.2/1.1.12/+download/gearmand-1.1.12.tar.gz

Comment: i followed the suggested process to install gearman, i got message Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/gearman.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/gearman-1.1.2  but when i run gearmand -d command it is still saying command not found, please suggest why it is happening when every thing has been installed as mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

For Debian, you should try this line:

```
sudo apt-get install libgearman2
```

instead of:

```
sudo apt-get install libgearman-dev
```

http://www.masnun.com/2011/09/30/installing-and-getting-started-with-gearman.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in this post [installing-gearman-php-extension-on-debian-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312207/installing-gearman-php-extension-on-debian-6).

On Debian 6 / squeeze you can only install up to version 0.8.3.
If you want a newer version, you have to upgrade to wheezy.

Answer (score 0):

You can find thorough installation instructions for 0.8.3 here:
http://blog.andyburton.co.uk/index.php/2012-12/gearman-0-41-with-mysql-persistent-storage-and-php-pecl-0-8-3-with-gearmanmanager-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Answer (score 0):

Please try the steps mentioned here:

http://www.daredevel.com/php-jobs-with-gearman-and-supervisor/

thanks