# How to install Gearman extension for php in Windows (XAMPP)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, gearman

I am developing a PHP project using Codeigniter.For my project I need to send email in background after user registration for email confirmation. So I decided to use Gearman. I think it is the only way. I do not want to use cron. But my problem is I cannot install Gearman extension using PECL. I tried the following ways. I cannot install it.

Using PECL:

```
pecl install gearman
```

I tried on this links as well

- [How to install Gearman with PHP Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982921/how-to-install-gearman-with-php-extension)
- http://www.phpvs.net/2010/11/30/installing-gearman-and-gearmand-on-windows-with-cygwin/ (This link keeps redirecting. Cannot open)

So how can I set up Gearman extension for windows? I cannot even find a link for that.

Comment: have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373363/how-can-i-install-gearman-php-extension-on-windows-os

Comment: Yes I did. It is not working. Is that possible to use CURL to that kind of thing ? I mean just on way message exchange pattern. So curl will not wait for it finish. Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes,if you do not at once have to letter to user

Comment: I dont need to show status. By default, CURL is two way pattern ? If it does what is the option to configure it as one way pattern ?