# Gearman installed on linux server, but not able to execute gearman commands

Tags: php, gearman

Iam new to Gearman and I have followed the procedure to install Gearman as suggested in [How to install Gearman with PHP Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982921/how-to-install-gearman-with-php-extension).

Installation procedure at the end displayed a message that Gearman has been successfully installed but when Iam executing command to start Gearman it is saying command not found.

```
command: gearmand -d
bash: gearmand: command not found
```

Message displayed post completion of installation is:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/gearman.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/gearman-1.1.2
```

Upon recheck installation it is clearly saying gearman is installed

```
pecl/gearman is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.1.2
```

Comment: If you on some of debian derivate `gearmand` is a part of `gearman-job-server` package. Run `apt-get install gearman-job-server` to install the package.

Comment: We are using centos

Comment: `gearmand` is not a part of php module `pecl/gearman`. Hence you've to install the daemon separately.

Comment: CentOS 7.x? There’s a gearmand package in the EPEL x86_64 repo. First, enable that repo if you haven’t. Then, just `yum install gearmand`. Alternatively, download the latest gearmand release from https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/releases, configure, and compile the source.

Answer (score 2):

[pecl/gearman](https://pecl.php.net/package/gearman) uses [libgearman](http://gearman.org/download/) library to provide API for communicating with [gearmand](http://gearman.org/download/), and writing clients and workers.

[gearmand](http://gearman.org/download/) is a daemon, which is not a part of [pecl/gearman](https://pecl.php.net/package/gearman), and should be installed separately.